# Убрать порт 80 из URL

Tags: node.js, https

У меня сайт запущен через `https` модуль в Node.js, и мой сайт почему-то недоступен если писать https://mydomain.com, надо писать именно https://mydomain.com:80.
Я использую `server.listen(80)`.

Comment: Ваш сервер должен слушать и 443-й порт

Comment: в идеале при подключении на 80й порт сделать редирект на https

Comment: у вас есть 2 варианта решения проблемы: 1) поставить и настроить nginx, настроить проксирование запросов в ваше приложение, получить сертификаты и организовать обработку защищённых соединений по протоколам https/http2/http3; 2) использовать инструменты nodejs https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener или https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example

Comment: Вадим, спасибо большое, это сработало.

Comment: Используй `server.listen(443);`